# Sequential async operations for each in Node JS

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async.js

I am working on a database migration. This requires querying one DB, getting an array of records and perform a set of async operations to insert the data in the new DB. In order to keep data consistency, I want to insert the records one at the time so I want each operation to run sequentially. The only way I have found to do these is using recursion.

Is there a cleaner way of doing this same thing? I know there is a library called async https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/ which I never tried before.

The recursive method I have written looks like this:

```
const insertItem = async (data) => {
    let item = data[0];

    if (!item) {
        //I am done return
        return;
    }

    try {
        //Do multiple await calls to insert record into new database
    } catch (e) {
        //Recover from error (DB rollbacks, etc)
    } finally {
        //Remove inserted or failed item from collection.
        data.shift();
        await insertItem(data);
    }
};

//Query original database
getInfo().then((data) => insertItem(data));
```

Comment: Why not just loop through the data? If you want it sync it sequentially just wait for promise to resolve before moving to next record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sync loop `for...of` it will wait for HTTP response.

```
const dataArr = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'];

async function processItems(arr){
  for(const el of arr) {
    const response = await insertData(el);    
    // add some code here to process the response.
  }
};

processItems(dataArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The posted code achieves iterating through the data collection (an array) retrieved from the first data base by using `data.shift` to mutate the argument array before calling the single function handling everything recursively.

To clean this up,  remove the `shift` and recursive calls by splitting the data processing function into two:

- one function to step through data retrieved from the first data base,
- a second function to insert records in the second data base as required.

This removes the need for the `.finally` clause and leaves the structure of the code looking more like

```
async function insertData(data) {
    for( let index = 0 ; index < data.length; ++index) {
        await insertItem( data[index]);
    }
}

async function insertItem( data) {
    try {
        //Do multiple await calls to insert record into new database
    } catch (e) {
        //Recover from error (DB rollbacks, etc)
        // throwing an error here aborts the caller, insertData()
    }
}

getInfo().then( insertData).catch( /*... handle fatal error ...*/);
```

Depending on preferred style, `insertItem` could be declared as nested function within `insertData` to keep it looking neat, and `insertData` could be written as an anonymous function argument of the `then` call after `getInfo()`.

It is possible, of course, to perform asynchronous operations sequentially be other means, but using `await` inside an `async` function is perhaps the simplest coding method.

Comment: Thank you @traktor53 . It does make sense and it is far better than my original code. However I believe what xMayank posted looks simpler.Thank you both!!!